# Strange File Reading Error

Tags: c, multithreading, pipe, fopen, fgets

This program uses pipes to pass messages between processes.  I compile with
gcc -Wall -o p2 p2.c INIT.DAT LOG.DAT TRANS1 TRANS2
I keep getting this error after compilation:

> /usr/bin/ld:INIT.DAT: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
>   /usr/bin/ld:INIT.DAT:1: syntax error

with this source code:

```
#include "my.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

   int pipe1[2], pipe2[2], pipe3[2];
   int pid[3];
   int p;
   int len, i, index, check, oneOrTwo;
   char val[10];
   char buff[MAXLINE];
   char strLog[MAXLINE];
   char* token;
   FILE *log, *trans1, *trans2, *init;
   //Create pipes
   p = pipe(pipe1);
   if(p < 0)
   {

      printf("pipe error");
      exit(0);

   }
   else
      printf("successful pipe1 = %d\n", p);

   p = pipe(pipe2);
   if(p < 0)
   {

      printf("pipe error");
      exit(0);

   }
   else
      printf("successful pipe2 = %d\n", p);

   p = pipe(pipe3);
   if(p < 0)
   {

      printf("pipe error");
      exit(0);

   }
   else
      printf("successful pipe3 = %d\n", p);

   //Store Manager
   pid[0] = fork();
   if(pid[0] == 0)
   {
      //Close unused channels
      if(close(pipe1[1]) == -1)
         printf("close error closing pipe1[1]\n");
      if(close(pipe2[0]) == -1)
         printf("close error closing pipe2[0]\n");
      if(close(pipe3[0]) == -1)
         printf("close error closing pipe3[0]\n");
      //open INI.DAT
      init = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      if(init == NULL)
      {

         printf("INIT.DAT failed to open");
         exit(0);

      }

      len = 0;
      //Gets TABLE size
      while(fgets(buff, MAXLINE, init) != NULL)
         len++;

      struct TABLE table[len];

      i = 0;
      init = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      //Fills table
      while(fgets(buff, MAXLINE, init) != NULL)
      {

         //id
         token = strtok(buff, " ");
         strcpy(table[i].id, token);
         //value
         token = strtok(NULL, " ");
         table[i].value = atoi(token);

         i++;

      }
      //Opens LOG.DAT
      log = fopen(argv[2], "r+");
      if(log == NULL)
      {

         printf("LOG.DAT failed to open");
         exit(0);

      }
      //Send and receive messages
      while(1)
      {

         check = 0;
         //Quit when pipe is closed
         if(read(pipe1[0], buff, MAXLINE) == -1)
            break;

         strcpy(strLog, "Store Manager received message: ");
         strcat(strLog, buff);
         fwrite(strLog, 1, sizeof(strLog), log);
         //1 or 2
         token = strtok(buff, " ");
         oneOrTwo = atoi(token);
         //pid
         token = strtok(NULL, " ");
         //U
         token = strtok(NULL, " ");
         //Update
         if(strcmp(token, "U") == 0)
         {
            //id
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");

            for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {

               if(token == table[i].id)
               {

                  check = 1;
                  index = i;

                  //value
                  token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                  table[i].value += atoi(token);

               }

            }
            //Update failed
            if(check == 0)
            {

               strcpy(strLog, "Store Manager sent message: Error updating table");
               fwrite(strLog, 1, sizeof(strLog), log);

               if(oneOrTwo == 1)
                  write(pipe2[1], "Error updating table", MAXLINE);
               else
                  write(pipe3[1], "Error updating table", MAXLINE);

            }
            //Update succeeded
            else
            {

               strcpy(strLog, "Store Manager sent message: U 0 ");
               strcat(strLog, table[index].id);
               strcat(strLog, " ");
               sprintf(val, "%d", table[index].value);
               strcat(strLog, val);

               fwrite(strLog, 1, sizeof(strLog), log);

               if(oneOrTwo == 1)
                  write(pipe2[1], strLog, MAXLINE);
               else
                  write(pipe3[1], strLog, MAXLINE);

            }

         }
         //Read
         else
         {

            check = 0;

            for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
               //Read succeeded
               if(token == table[i].id)
               {

                  check = 1;
                  strcpy(strLog, "Store Manager sent message: R ");
                  sprintf(val, "%d", oneOrTwo);
                  strcat(strLog, val);
                  strcat(strLog, " ");
                  strcat(strLog, table[i].id);
                  strcat(strLog, " 0");

                  fwrite(strLog, 1, sizeof(strLog), log);

                  if(oneOrTwo == 1)
                     write(pipe2[1], strLog, MAXLINE);
                  else
                     write(pipe3[1], strLog, MAXLINE);

               }

            }
            //Read failed
            if(check == 0)
            {

               strcpy(strLog, "Store Manager sent message: Error reading table");

               fwrite(strLog, 1, sizeof(strLog), log);

               if(oneOrTwo == 1)
                  write(pipe2[1], "Error reading table", MAXLINE);
               else
                  write(pipe3[1], "Error updareadingting table", MAXLINE);

            }

         }

      }
      //Close files and quit process
      fclose(init);
      fclose(log);
      exit(0);
   }
   //P1
   pid[1] = fork();
   if(pid[1] == 0)
   {
      //Close unused channels
      if(close(pipe1[0]) == -1)
         printf("close error closing pipe1[0]\n");
      if(close(pipe2[1]) == -1)
         printf("close error closing pipe2[1]\n");
      //Open LOG.DAT
      log = fopen(argv[2], "r+");
      if(log == NULL)
      {

         printf("LOG.DAT failed to open");
         exit(0);

      }
      //Open TRANS1
      trans1 = fopen(argv[3], "r");
      if(log == NULL)
      {

         printf("LOG.DAT failed to open");
         exit(0);

      }
      //Send and receive messages
      while(fgets(buff, MAXLINE, trans1) != NULL)
      {

         strcpy(strLog, "Process 1 sent message: ");
         strcat(strLog, buff);

         fwrite(strLog, 1, sizeof(strLog), log);

         write(pipe1[1], buff, MAXLINE);

         read(pipe2[0], buff, MAXLINE);

         strcpy(strLog, "Process 1 received message: ");
         strcat(strLog, buff);

         fwrite(strLog, 1, sizeof(strLog), log);

         sleep(3);

      }
      //Close files and quit process
      fclose(trans1);
      fclose(log);
      exit(0);

   }
   //P2
   pid[2] = fork();
   if(pid[2] == 0)
   {
      //Close unused channels
      if(close(pipe1[0]) == -1)
         printf("close error closing pipe1[0]\n");
      if(close(pipe3[1]) == -1)
         printf("close error closing pipe3[1]\n");
      //Open LOG.DAT
      log = fopen(argv[2], "r+");
      if(log == NULL)
      {

         printf("LOG.DAT failed to open");
         exit(0);

      }
      //Open TRANS2
      trans2 = fopen(argv[4], "r");
      if(log == NULL)
      {

         printf("LOG.DAT failed to open");
         exit(0);

      }
      //Send and receive messages
      while(fgets(buff, MAXLINE, trans1) != NULL)
      {

         strcpy(strLog, "Process 1 sent message: ");
         strcat(strLog, buff);

         fwrite(strLog, 1, sizeof(strLog), log);

         write(pipe1[1], buff, MAXLINE);

         read(pipe3[0], buff, MAXLINE);

         strcpy(strLog, "Process 1 received message: ");
         strcat(strLog, buff);

         fwrite(strLog, 1, sizeof(strLog), log);

         sleep(3);

      }
      //Close files and quit process
      fclose(trans2);
      fclose(log);
      exit(0);

   }
   //Wait for processes to quit
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
   {

      if(waitpid(pid[i], NULL, 0) == -1)
      {

         printf("waitpid error");
         exit(0);

      }

   }

}
```

with these input files:
I

```
(NOT IN FILE) INIT.DAT
DISNEY 3  
INTEL 56
```

Hate

```
(NOT IN FILE) TRANS1
R XXXX  
R DISNEY
```

This

```
(NOT IN FILE) TRANS2
R INTEL  
U INTEL 45  
U DISNEY 21  
U DISNEY 21  
R DISNEY  
U DISNEY 21  
U DIY 21
```

Formatting

```
LOG.DAT is empty.
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error, because even if I change INIT.DAT to INIT.txt or any other file format, it still doesn't work.  It has to be an issue with my code, but I can't see it.

Thanks.

Comment: When/where does this error occur?

Comment: Is not this a linker error "/usr/bin/ld:INIT.DAT:1: syntax error"?  If so, not a code problem, but a compilation one.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Do you want us to deduce it from the code?

Comment: How are you compiling the code? I bet it contains some `./*` part..

Comment: The program is just supposed to pass messages between processes using pipes.  I compile with: gcc -Wall -o p2 p2.c INIT.DAT LOG.DAT TRANS1 TRANS2

Comment: The source code might be irrelevant here. What's the compile(`gcc`)/link command that you use in order to generate the executable?

Comment: Try `gcc -Wall -o p2 p2.c`.

Comment: In other words -- Why are you including `INIT.DAT LOG.DAT TRANS1 TRANS2` in your compile string?

Comment: Yeah that fixed it, thanks.  Now to fix the rest of my program!

Comment: the header file: `my.h` is not part of the posted code, so it is a bit difficult to test.   However, I would strongly suggest using: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c p2.c -o p2.o -I.`  followed by: `gcc p2.o -o p2`   To separate the compile step from the link step.  And notice the expanded parameters in the compile step so the compiler will output all the warnings

Comment: when compiled with the proper warnings enabled, the compiler will raise warnings that indicate `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <sys/wait.h>` and `#include <unistd.h> are missing. And unused variables like: `strlog` and `buff` and `table`.  And variables set but not used like: `index`.  And unused parameters like: `argc'.   Note never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered